# How to get zonal statistics of a vector map by areas from another vector map in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis, clip, zonal-statistics

I have a map with areas (polygons) and another map with lines for example. Lines have multiple attributes and I want some of them to be summed and written to new columns of my areas map. Each polygon would get a sum of attribute values from lines clipped by this polygon, how can I do this? For rasters it's called zonal statistics.
I should be something like v.vect.stats but not for points.
I haven't found an appropriate tool in v. of GRASS.

UPD: I think that I would begin with v.ovelay by lines and areas with operator=and. Thus I will have line layer with my areas numbers, some of them will duplicate of course. Then I should aggregate or join lines by numbers of my areas column. But how?

UPD2: It seems that v.dissolve on area number column suits the task, but after execution database connection is lost. It's clear, as the number of rows changes. So what's the rigth operation that reconnects the new layer with database and joins all columns in one table. Values from lines vector map should be summed.

UPD3: Well, I realized that v.dissolve won't sum attribute values, so it doesn't suit

Comment: I created a specific question about aggregating features:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475827/what-is-the-right-way-to-dissolve-vector-features-in-grass-gis-on-attribute-valu